# How to select a range of NumPy values for bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I created a bar chart using Matplotlib from the count of unique strings in a NumPy array. Now I would like to display only the top 10 most frequent species in the bar chart. I am new to Python so I am having trouble figuring it out. This is also my first question here, so let me know if I'm missing any important information

```
test_indices = numpy.where((obj.year == 2014) & (obj.native == "Native"))
SpeciesList2014 = numpy.append(SpeciesList2014, obj.species_code[test_indices])

labels, counts = numpy.unique(SpeciesList2014, return_counts=True)
indexSort = numpy.argsort(counts)
plt.bar(labels[indexSort][::-1], counts[indexSort][::-1], align='center')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.show()
```

Comment: is `obj` a pandas dataframe? it would be more straightforward to do this directly on the pandas side

Comment: No, it's all using numpy. This is just a piece of a larger set of code that I got from my boss and I don't want to pick it apart since I'm a noob. If there are any suggestions to do it using numpy arrays, that would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the values in a sorted array but you only want to select the ten values with the most counts.

It seems your array is sorted with larger counts as last values so you can exploit the numpy indexing as

```
plt.bar(labels[indexSort][-1:-11:-1], counts[indexSort][-1:-11;-1], align='center')
```

where `[a:b:c]` means a=start index, b=end index c= step, and negative values represent counting from the end of the array.
Or alternatively:

```
n=counts.shape[0]
plt.bar(labels[indexSort][n-11:], counts[indexSort][n-11:], align='center')
```

which plots in increasing order.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you! And thank you for explaining the start and end indexes, that makes much more sense.

Comment: Nice glad to help. Numpy's indexing can be very powerful. If that resolved your question please consider marking the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor and learn about [Numpy Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html).

In this simple case, the last 10 elements of an array are indicated by the notation `[-10:]`, that you can read from the last element minus ten to the last element.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# syntetic data
np.random.seed(20210428)
SpeciesList2014 = np.random.randint(0, 100, 2000)

# this is from your code
species, counts = np.unique(SpeciesList2014, return_counts=True)
topindices = np.argsort(counts)[-10:]

# here you probably can have, simply, topspecies = species[topindices]
topspecies = [repr(label) for label in species[topindices]]
topcounts  = counts[topindices]

# plotting
plt.bar(topspecies, topcounts)
plt.show()
```

[image]